# Reuse item variable in ansible loop

Tags: loops, ansible, yaml

I have the following variable:

```
public_binaries:
  - version: 1.11.3
    url: "https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/releases/download/v{{ item.version | default('1') }}/gitea-{{ item.version | default('1') }}-linux-amd64"
  - version: 0.6.1
    url: "https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/v{{ item.version | default('1') }}/dockerize-linux-amd64-v{{ item.version | default('1') }}.tar.gz"
```

As you can see, I try to reuse the version value in the same item. But so far, no success. What kind of loop should I use ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Michée, welcome to SO. We cannot **guess** what you are trying to do based on that snippet. If it's in a `vars` file, you cannot use jinja2 templates there; if it's in a playbook, then post the playbook [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck

Comment: It is in a `vars` file. But I think I will do otherwise. I will split versions and urls in 2 separate variables and call one in the other.